# HTCondor: DAGMan input file priority vs job submit description file priority

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, condor, htcondor

In [HTCondor](https://htcondor.org/), what priority has greater precedence (if both are provided): the one specified for a job in the [DAGMan](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-manual/dagman-workflows.html) input file or the one provided in the job submit description file?

For example, if one has in the DAGMan input file:

```
JOB MyJob MyJob.sub
PRIORITY MyJob 1
```

and at the same time, in `MyJob.sub`:

```
priority = 2
```

What priority will be assigned to the job `MyJob`, 1 or 2?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an answer to my question:

> DAGMan will override any priority command placed in a submit description file (unless the effective node priority is 0; in this case, any priority specified in the submit file will take effect).